# update-alternatives for ant

Tags: ant, ubuntu-14.04

Can I use update-alternatives on ubuntu to switch between multiple versions of ant? I used the same for switching between g++ versions on ubuntu 14.04 LTS as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version). Looking for a similar process for multiple ant versions, but not able to find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is how I did it. Luckily, I found the solution soon after posting the question. I should have tried different keywords in google search. Searching "Installing multiple ant versions on ubuntu" took me to [this link](https://zefr.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/multiple-versions-of-apache-ant-on-ubuntu/). Here are the steps that I followed. I had version 1.9.x on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04) and I needed ant 1.8.4:

```
$ wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.8.4-bin.tar.bz2
// move current version to stock
$ test -f /usr/share/ant || sudo mv /usr/share/ant /usr/share/apache-ant-stock
$ tar xvf apache-ant-1.8.4-bin.tar.bz2
$ sudo mv apache-ant-1.8.4 /usr/share/
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/ant ant-bins /usr/share/apache-ant-1.8.4/ 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/ant ant-bins /usr/share/apache-ant-stock/ 2
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ant ant /usr/share/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin/ant 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ant ant /usr/share/apache-ant-stock/bin/ant 2
$ sudo update-alternatives --config ant-bins
$ sudo update-alternatives --config ant
```

Now I can switch the versions.